# Angular datepicker payload value differs from console log

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

In my app (made with Angular 7.1.4 + Angular Material) I have a form with a date picker field. I am console.log-ing the choosen date and the loged result is correct. But when I look at the payload in Network what was sent to my database the date is one day behind... how and why? how do I fix this? Is the issue in the locale? Do I have to make a custom date format?

Here is my code:
edit-offer.component.html:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="expirationForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdatePonudba(offer.id)">
                        <mat-form-field class="form-control">
                            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Datum zapadlosti" formControlName="datumZapadlosti">
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <br/>
                        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn-primary">SHRANI</button>
                    </form>
```

edit-offer.component.ts:

```
onUpdatePonudba(offerID) {

    const validDate = this.expirationForm.controls['datumZapadlosti'].value;
    console.log(offerID);
    console.log(validDate);

    this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}offers/valid-date`, {
        offer_id: offerID,
        valid_date: validDate
    }).subscribe(
        data => {

        },
        error => {
            console.log("Error", error);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to a similar issue recently. According to the moment docs when a moment object is converted into JSON it is adjusted to UTC. Depending on the time zone you are running your app in this could cause the date you are sending to your server to represent the previous day.

To fix this I converted the object to an ISO8601 string using `moment.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')`. Then passed it to my POST request. Another option might be to update the server to be able to properly handle UTC but for me that isn't an option right now.

In your code you could add something like:

```
{
    offer_id: offerID,
    valid_date: validDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
}
```

You can omit 'THH:mm:ss' if you don't need the time portion.

Comment: I'm really new to all of this, could you help me wit a code example of how to do this? do I have to make a custom pipe or something?

Comment: I added an edit to my answer.

Comment: now I am getting this error validDate.format is not a function at push../src/app/offers/edit-offer/edit-offer.component.ts.EditOfferComponent.onUpdatePonudba